# LIMPIAR SELECT2 CON HTML + C# + JQUERY

Tags: html, c#, jquery, ajax, select2

En esta oportunidad les comparto un problema que se me ha presentado, pasa que no se limpia un select2 con jquery cuando pulso un botón de limpiar formulario, mi código es el siguiente:

**Tener en cuenta que en el select uso una clase: class="select2"**

**FORMULARIO QUE DE REQUIERE LIMPIAR EL SELECT CON EL BOTÓN LIMPIAR**

```
<form id="idform" >
    <select id="cargosID" class="select2"  name="cargosID">
    @{ 
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">-- Seleccionar Cargo--</option>
    }
    @{
    foreach (var item in Model.ListaCargos)
    {
    if (Model.cargosID == item.cargosID)
    {
    <text>
    <option selected value="@item.cargosID">@item.name</option>
    </text>    
    }
    else
    {
    <text>
    <option value="@item.cargosID">@item.name</option>
    </text> 
    }
    }   
    }
    </select>

 </form >
```

**CÓDIGO EN JQUERY**

```
$("#btnClean").click(function (event) {
$("#idform")[0].reset();
});
```

Con el código Jquery solo limpia campos d texto pero campos con lista no lo hace, por favor su apoyo con este problema. Saludos.

Comment: reset el form y limpiar valores del select2 por separado $("#btnClean").click(function (event) {
$("#idform").reset();
$('#cargosID').val([]);
});

Comment: Sigue el problema

Answer (score 1):

Solo asignale el valor `""` (vacio) a tu select

```
$("#btnClean").click(function (event) {
    $("#idform")[0].reset();
    $("#cargosID").val("");
});
```